# Adding a extra path after domain

Tags: php, url, redirect

If trying to add a extra path in URL after my domain in all urls

```
$extra = "en";
$domain = "http://domain.com";
$current = currentURL();
$rest_path = str_replace($domain,'',$current);
$result = $domain."/".$extra.$rest_path;

// $result is "http://domain.com/en/mysub/mysub"
```

After this so I redirect my site via using PHP redirect

**To get current url is doing like..**

```
function currentURL() {
    $pageURL=(@$_SERVER["HTTPS"]=="on")?"https://":"http://";
        if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]!="80"){
            $pageURL.=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }else{
            $pageURL.=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;
}
```

It's look like many steps , Any easier to do that ? Or review my bad coding pls.

PS : Try to do without using `.htaccess`

Comment: looks like a job for the .htaccess file.

Comment: Oh @RickCalder forgot to say , try to do without using .htaccess

Comment: hah, okay fair enough.

Comment: any review ? @RickCalder

Comment: looks fine to me, I would take out the "@" before $_SERVER and sanitize with an isset(), as it's a bad practice to use it (use it only on develpment)

Comment: dunno, why not just do a str_replace .com with ".com/".$extra  on $_SERVER? Are you doing this on a different domain or does the domain always stay the same?

Comment: I tried you code and it worked. My guess is something else messes things up.

Comment: You probably should use the `.htaccess` for this, because it's application-level routing not page-level routing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$extra = 'en';
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$new_url=str_replace('.com','.com/'.$extra,$domain);
```

No?

Comment: Say agian , Good idea ! :D

Comment: eh, yeah the original wouldn't have worked, sorry. Pretty sure that will though.

Comment: Pretty sure it won't matter what the base is unless it doesn't have .com in it. Mihai's solution makes more sense in the case where you want to change the domain base since you can specify what it is.

Comment: like `str_replace('.com/mybase','.com/mybase/'.$extra,$domain)` ?

Comment: wait a sec , will test agian

Answer (score 2):

I would use just:

```
$extra = "en";
$domain = "http://domain.com";
$result = $domain."/".$extra.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

since you are not using protocol or domain name.